# query errors in transaction model use with pgbouncer

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm, pgbouncer

I use pgbouncer as pg  connection pool,if I set pool_mode=Transaction in pgbouncer.ini,my app happens error when query db(app writed with go)：

```
(pq: bind message supplies 19 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 20)
(pq: bind message supplies 22 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 20
(pq: bind message supplies 22 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 19)
(pq: bind message supplies 6 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 22)
```

But  I modify pool_mode=Session,It runs ok.
what may be wrong if I set the pool_mode = Transaction .

Comment: https://pgbouncer.github.io/faq.html#how-to-use-prepared-statements-with-transaction-pooling do you use prepared statements?

Comment: I use https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm  lib as query.It supposed to use prepared statememt,I view the pgbouncer doc.it disabled prepared statements in the client,so if I want to use transaction pooling,I have to try another way?(my english is not well)@Vao Tsun

Comment: I suppose. you either use prepared statements. or pooling in session mode